# mwlresizable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, resize

I am trying to resize a picture, but on mouse up, the picture just moves to the new position without resizing.

```html
<img id=image1
       ngDraggable
       mwlResizable
       [enableGhostResize]="true"
       [resizeEdges]="{bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true}"
       (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
       src="{{user.picture}}">
```

component.ts:

```js
import { ResizeEvent } from "angular-resizable-element";

export class Component{

  onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
    console.log('Element was resized', event);
  }
}
```

app.module:

```js
...
import {ResizableModule} from "angular-resizable-element";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    HttpClientModule,
    AngularDraggableModule,
    ResizableModule
  ],
  providers: [GetJsonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I did everything by the book

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @lavor Just updated the question to more details

Answer (score 14):

In case its still useful for anyone. You need to apply width and height in onResizeEnd function:

Change component code to this:

```
import { ResizeEvent } from "angular-resizable-element";

export class Component{
   style: {};
   onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
      this.style = {
        width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
        height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
      };
  }
}
```

Change HTML code to this:

```
<img id=image1
       ngDraggable
       mwlResizable
       [enableGhostResize]="true"
       [resizeEdges]="{bottom: true, right: true, top: true, left: true}"
       (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
       src="{{user.picture}}" [ngStyle]="style">
```

Comment: Nice they are missing that from documentation

Comment: can we get % instead of px .?

Comment: This may be the most horrible npm ever created. So many trouble to make it work is not even funny. I ended up using ng2-dragula which is not for the same purpose but works perfect.